# Meteor app would never run on Android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-virtual-device, meteor-cordova

I have a Meteor with Cordova app. It perfectly runs on iOS Simulator and iOS device, and `meteor build` produces correct output for iOS. But if I do

```
$ meteor run android
```

then I get into a situation when Android virtual device is launched but the app isn't on it, while on the console I see "Starting app on Android Emulator" with perpetual spinner. On the virtual device, once it has loaded, there's an alert box that says "Unfortunately, Launcher3 has stopped".

Where should I look for a solution? What are possible things that are missing so that I can't have the app delivered to the emulator and be running on it?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue. I didn't find a way to make it work under a virtual device.

But, as I didn't have enough log messages with meteor, I tried to run a cordova app ([the main tuto](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted) from the official site).

I found that I needed Java8 SDK whereas I was using Java6. Cordova console showed me something like :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I guess you'll find some usefull debug messages.

After fixing some bugs, it didn't work back on my meteor App.

Then, I tried with a real device and it worked like a charm !

Have you tried Genymotion or any other emulator ?

Regards